# wordpressのテーマアップロード時に「ダウンロードに失敗しました。 要求されたリクエストを完了できる HTTP トランスポートがありません」と表示される問題

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

[image: 画面スクリーンショット]
よろしくお願いします。

Windows8.1
php 5.4.39
Apache 2.2.14
localでの実行です。

WordPressに自作テーマをアップロードした所、

> ダウンロードに失敗しました。 要求されたリクエストを完了できる HTTP トランスポートがありません。

と表示されました。

プレビューしてみると自分の大体思った通りの形で表示されていたので、
おそらくサーバーの何かが問題になっていると考えています。

php.iniの

> extension=php_curl.dll

こちらは有効化しています。
Apacheの再起動も試しました。

Apacheの実行ユーザの設定を行う必要があるのでしょうか？
httpd.confのUserとGroupをApachiに変更するのでしょうか。

設定の仕方がサイトによって様々で理解しきれないので助けていただきたいです。

最終的には、Wordpresのテーマアップロード時に上記のエラー文が出ないでしっかりとアップロードさせたいです。
(自動更新が可能な状態？)

少しでも情報が欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

> extension=php_curl.dll 
>   extension=php_openssl.dll

この2つを有効化することで動きました。